# site map xml generation - Getting publish status of structure group and page adding performance overhead

Tags: 2011, templating, tom.net

We are using Tridion 2011 SP1. While generating site map XML in .NET templating code, we came across an issue. The requirement is to show only those structure group/pages in site map XML that are published against the publication target for which the site map xml is currently generated. For this we are using below API call.

```
PublishEngine.IsPublished(structureGroup, engine.PublishingContext.PublicationTarget, true);
```

The above call will be made against each structure group and page and hence is causing performance overhead in generating sitemap XML.

Is there any better way to achieve solution for above? For example: is there any API call available that accepts bulk structure group/page ids and return the publish status for them in a single shot?

Comment: Do keep in mind that Structure Groups are rarely published - you publish the pages within the SG, not the SG itself.

Comment: Do you need to publish the navigation XML that often that it impacts everything else? Would you consider using dynamic linking instead?

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
        Filter filter = new Filter();
        filter.Conditions["ItemType"] = 68;//pages, structure groups
        filter.BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.Extended;

        XmlElement childItems = sg.GetListItems(filter);
        foreach (XmlElement item in childItems.SelectNodes("*"))
        {
            string isPublished = item.GetAttribute("IsPublished");
        }
```

Note, the Filter class is now deprecated, so you should switch this up for one of the new Filters, however, the concept is the same.

Have a look at the code here:
http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/web-sitemap

The BaseColumns.Extended property loads the following additional properties when you call GetListItems(filter): IsPublished, IsShared, IsLocalized, SubType (for schemas: purpose, for template: template type), FileExt (file extension of multimedia data), Trustee (name of revisor). Only applies to ListItems.

For full descriptions of the properties see here (login required):
http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_10E4754436F449ED9E96518C50E23EDD

Comment: Thanks for the response. The above code works fine if there exists a single publication target for the tridion instance, as there is no mention of publication target against which the item(page/structuregroup) is published. Is there any way in above code snippet that I can pass publication target to filter the results?

Comment: For that you will need to use Engine, which you wanted to avoid.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way to get the publishing status for batch of pages/structure groups in a single shot using API?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  However, what you can do is implement a Child Sitemap feature.  This way you can split up your site structure into several sitemap files which you can publish in separate threads.  This should help with your performance issue.

Comment: Yes there is. Please see my answer.

Comment: Let's see some code then :)

Answer (score 3):

I would look at leveraging Tridion's own resolving functionality. If you call `StructureGroupResolver.Resolve()` with a resolve instruction that uses `ResolvePurpose.RePublish`, you can get a list of pages that are currently published to the target in question. You can use this list to exclude non-published items from your sitemap.

Comment: Can you please show a more complete example of this approach?  How would it work if we don't have any ResolveItems for an SG since we only have a list from GetListItems() of all pages and SGs, and what if the item in question is Page, not an SG?

Comment: If a republish resolve of the root structure group doesn't return any pages, then there are no pages published to your target in that publication. For a site map, you are really only interested in pages, not structure groups.